# I am facing this error during Execute the command at cmd :ant makexsltreports

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
build.xm:76: Exceute failed: java.io.IOException:
cannot run program "{browser}":CreateProcess error=2,The system can not find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start<ProcessBuilder.java:1047>
at java.lang.Runtime.exec<Runtime.java:617>
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.java13CommandLauncher.exec<Java13CommandLauncher.java:58>  

ant clean
ant compile
ant makesxltreports
```

getting error after execute this cmd
This code is working fine on virtual machine

please assist me 
build.xml file is given below

```
<project name="VoicePortal" basedir=".">

    <property name="home.dir" value="${basedir}"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="${home.dir}/build"/>
    <property name="src.dir" value="${home.dir}/src"/>
    <property name="ng.result" value="test-output"/>
    <property name="lib.dir" value="C:/seleniumjavaclient/framework jars_1"/>
    <property name="index.dir" value = "${basedir}/testng_output/index.html"/>

<!-- setClassPath -->
    <target name="setClassPath">
        <path id="classpath_jars">
            <pathelement path="${basedir}/" />
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
        </path>
        <pathconvert pathsep=":" property="test.classpath" refid="classpath_jars" />
    </target>

<!-- loadTestNG -->
    <target name="loadTestNG" depends="setClassPath">
      <taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="${test.classpath}"/>
    </target>

<!-- build -->
    <target name="build">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <tstamp>
            <format property="timestamp" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy_(HH-mm-ss)"/>
        </tstamp>
        <property name="build.log.dir" location="${basedir}/buildlogs"/>
        <mkdir dir="${build.log.dir}"/>
        <property name="build.log.filename" value="build_${timestamp}.log"/>
        <record name="${build.log.dir}/${build.log.filename}" loglevel="verbose" append="false"/>
        <echo message="build logged to ${build.log.filename}"/>
    </target>

<!-- Clean -->
    <target name="clean">
        <echo message="deleting existing build directory"/>
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

<!-- Compile -->
    <target name="compile" depends="clean,build,setClassPath,loadTestNG">
        <echo message="classpath:${test.classpath}"/>
        <echo message="compiling.........."/>
        <javac destdir="${build.dir}" srcdir="${src.dir}" classpath="${test.classpath}" includeantruntime="false"/>
    </target>

<!-- executeApp -->
    <target name="run" depends="compile">
        <testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${build.dir}">
            <xmlfileset dir="${basedir}" includes="testng.xml"/>
        </testng>
    </target>

<!-- Report --> 
    <target name="report" depends="run">
        <delete dir="${basedir}/testng-xslt"/>
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/testng-xslt"/>
        <xslt in="${basedir}/test-output/testng-results.xml"
        style="${basedir}/testng-results.xsl" out="${basedir}/testng-xslt/index.html" processor="SaxonLiaison">
            <param expression="${basedir}/testng-xslt/" name="testNgXslt.outputDir"/>
            <param expression="true" name="testNGXslt.sortTestCaseLinks"/>
            <param expression="FAIL,SKIP,PASS,BY_CLASS" name="testNgXslt.testDetailsFilter"/>
            <param expression="true" name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals"/>
            <classpath refid="classpath_jars"/>
        </xslt>
    </target>

<!-- makexsltreports-->
    <target name="makexsltreports" depends="report">
        <exec executable="${browser}" spawn="yes">
       <arg line="${index.dir}" />
      </exec>
     </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

${browser} is not specified in property name.

```
 <property name="browser" location="C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"/>
```

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: please refer this link for more explanation http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

Comment: i am able to execute only one page.But again getting same issuees.

Comment: <property name="browser" value="C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"/>This property takes me on google at the end of page.

Comment: Hi, i bit confused, what happens on "ant makesxltreports" is it not opening testng_output/index.html in firefox ?

Comment: The problem has been resolve .Thank you so much Murali :)

Comment: Hi Murali, Yes you are right some times the xslt report is not generated.